# Is it safe to immediately put food for heating right from the refrigerator?

Tags: food-safety, food-poisoning

Is it safe? Or should we make the food comes to room temperature and then heat it?

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly safe to cook food right from the refrigerator. In fact, that's the safest approach to avoid having your food spend excess time in the "Danger Zone":

> Leaving food out too long at room temperature can cause bacteria (such
>   as Staphylococcus aureus, Salmonella Enteritidis, Escherichia coli
>   O157:H7, and Campylobacter) to grow to dangerous levels that can cause
>   illness. Bacteria grow most rapidly in the range of temperatures
>   between 40 °F [4 °C] and 140 °F[60 °C], doubling in number in as little as 20
>   minutes. This range of temperatures is often called the "Danger Zone."

There is a hard limit on how long food can remain in the Danger Zone:

> Never leave food out of refrigeration over 2 hours. If the temperature
>   is above 90 °F, food should not be left out more than 1 hour.

And be aware that time spent in the danger zone is cumulative. So, for example, suppose you go to the market and buy some meat and it takes you an hour to finish your shopping and get home, where you then put the meat in the refrigerator. Now when you take that meat out later to cook it, it can only spend a maximum of *one* hour at room temperature. (Or if the temperature is over 90 °F[32 °C], it has no time left and you need to cook it immediately.)

http://www.fsis.usda.gov/wps/portal/fsis/topics/food-safety-education/get-answers/food-safety-fact-sheets/safe-food-handling/danger-zone-40-f-140-f/CT_Index

Answer (score -1):

I agree that it is dangerous, but a famous chef made the comment that he allows his steaks to come to room temperature because if the steak is cold and put into a hot pan the meat will seize up and become tough.  I think the bacteria tend to grow on the surface of the meat more and that is the part that is in extreme temperature.

Chopped meats, because they are exposed to air when going through the grinder, are a greater danger to you and should be cooked more thoroughly than steak.

Comment: Bringing meat to room temperature before cooking is purely a culinary question, and as long as it sits out no longer than 1-2 hours that should be safe. You're right about the ground meat but a reference backing that up would be expected here. Shouldn't be hard to find one.

Answer (score -1):

You should leave the food in the natural room temperature to give the iced water droops inside the food to melt so when the food heated, only minimal heat is needed to heat the whole food parts and equally in temperature.

Comment: Welcome to health SE :-). On Health it is required that answers are supported by references. Answers without them risk being deleted. You can always [edit] your question to add some. Thanks!